# How to retain first line of a file while printing lines between certain pattern?

Tags: sed

I am trying to delete lines falling between patterns starting with <0>::

```
Shikha 123
ABC::
0 0 1 May  8 00:03:17 2019
no comment
ABC#rra#:L
1 1 2 May  8 00:03:18 2019
no comment
CDE::
0 0 1 May  8 00:03:17 2019
no comment
```

I can do that using following sed command

```
 sed -n -e '/::/,/#rra#:/{ /#rra#:/d; p; }
```

Unfortunately, this pattern forgets everything before first pattern starting with <0>:: nd prints only

```
ABC::
0 0 1 May  8 00:03:17 2019
no comment
CDE::
0 0 1 May  8 00:03:17 2019
no comment
```

I need to retain first line also, which is being deleted by above sed command. Is there a way I can retain first line also along with above code i.e...

```
Shikha 123
ABC::
0 0 1 May  8 00:03:17 2019
no comment
CDE::
0 0 1 May  8 00:03:17 2019
no comment
```

Appreciate your help in advance.

Regards, Shikha

Comment: How about just adding `1,/::/p`? Oh, it prints the first `::` line twice then… I have to go now, will have a look at it later this day!

Comment: Which lines do you want to remove exactly? The `rra` line and the following lines until the next `::` line?

Comment: Thanks @dessert. Yes, absolutely correct. I have a written a hack of reading first line(Shikha 123) using head -1 file >tmp and then concatenate that to begining of lambda file. But thats slows the performance, hence, looking for a better way.

Comment: Wait, it’s always just the first line? Then `sed -n '1p;/::/,/#rra#:/{/#rra#:/d;p}'` would do.